# Swift - Remove Trailing Zeros From Double

Tags: ios, swift, double, trailing

What is the function that removes trailing zeros from doubles?

```
var double = 3.0
var double2 = 3.10

println(func(double)) // 3
println(func(double2)) // 3.1
```

Comment: A *double* does not have trailing zeros, only its *string representation*. Have a look at `NSNumberFormatter` or `String(format: ...)`.  There should already be some examples for both here on SO.

Comment: You could also use numberFormatter as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663996/format-string-with-trailing-zeros-removed-for-x-decimal-places-in-swift/30664610

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - How to remove a decimal from a float if the decimal is equal to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390466/swift-how-to-remove-a-decimal-from-a-float-if-the-decimal-is-equal-to-0)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In Swift 4 you can do it like that:

```
extension Double {
    func removeZerosFromEnd() -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 16 //maximum digits in Double after dot (maximum precision)
        return String(formatter.string(from: number) ?? "")
    }
}
```

example of use: `print (Double("128834.567891000").removeZerosFromEnd())` 
result: 128834.567891

You can also count how many decimal digits has your string:

```
import Foundation

extension Double {
    func removeZerosFromEnd() -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = (self.components(separatedBy: ".").last)!.count
        return String(formatter.string(from: number) ?? "")
    }
}
```

Comment: it converts "0.517" to ".517" . which could not be requirement of few people

Comment: I think you can just use "formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1" in that case.

Answer (score 83):

You can do it this way but it will return a string:

```
var double = 3.0
var double2 = 3.10

func forTrailingZero(_ temp: Double) -> String {
    var tempVar = String(format: "%g", temp)
    return tempVar
}

forTrailingZero(double)   //3
forTrailingZero(double2)  //3.1
```

Comment: Note that the "%g" format switches to the scientific notation if the number becomes too large: `forTailingZero(123456789) == 1.23457e+08` :)

Comment: I think the more optimal solution is described in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30664610/2859764

Answer (score 26):

## Removing trailing zeros in output

This scenario is good when the default output precision is desired. We test the value for potential trailing zeros, and we use a different output format depending on it.

```
extension Double {
    var stringWithoutZeroFraction: String {
        return truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}
```

(works also with `extension Float`, but not `Float80`)

Output:

> 1.0 → "1"
> 0.1 → "0.1"
> 0.01 → "0.01"
> 0.001 → "0.001"
> 0.0001 → "0.0001"

## Formatting with maximum fraction digits, without trailing zeros

This scenario is good when a custom output precision is desired.
This solution seems roughly as fast as NumberFormatter + NSNumber [solution from MirekE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31390870/1033581), but one benefit could be that we're avoiding NSObject here.

```
extension Double {
    func string(maximumFractionDigits: Int = 2) -> String {
        let s = String(format: "%.\(maximumFractionDigits)f", self)
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: -maximumFractionDigits, by: -1) {
            if s[s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: i - 1)] != "0" {
                return String(s[..<s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: i)])
            }
        }
        return String(s[..<s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -maximumFractionDigits - 1)])
    }
}
```

(works also with `extension Float`, but not `Float80`)

Output for `maximumFractionDigits: 2`:

> 1.0 → "1"
> 0.12 → "0.12"
> 0.012 → "0.01"
> 0.0012 → "0"
> 0.00012 → "0"

Note that it performs a rounding (same as MirekE solution):

> 0.9950000 → "0.99"
> 0.9950001 → "1"

Comment: when `maximumFractionDigits` = 0, 254.99998480081558 ==> "25"

Answer (score 4):

In case you're looking how to remove trailing zeros from a **string**:

```
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "^([\d,]+)$|^([\d,]+)\.0*$|^([\d,]+\.[0-9]*?)0*$", with: "$1$2$3", options: .regularExpression)
```

This will transform strings like "0.123000000" into "0.123"

Comment: The simplest way to go is usually the easiest.

Comment: if the input is "63.00" output will be "63." which is wrong

Answer (score 3):

All the answers i found was good but all of them had some problems like producing decimal numbers without the `0` in the beginning ( like `.123` instead of `0.123`). but these two will do the job with no problem :

```
extension Double {
    func formatNumberWithFixedFraction(maximumFraction: Int = 8) -> String {
        let stringFloatNumber = String(format: "%.\(maximumFraction)f", self)
        return stringFloatNumber
    }
    
    func formatNumber(maximumFraction: Int = 8) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = maximumFraction
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.allowsFloats = true
        let formattedNumber = formatter.string(from: number).unwrap
        return formattedNumber
    }
}
```

The first one converts `71238.12` with maxFraction of 8 to: `71238.12000000`
but the second one with maxFraction of 8 converts it to: `71238.12`

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me, returning it as a `String` for a text label

```
func ridZero(result: Double) -> String {
        let value = String(format: "%g", result)
        return value
}
```

Following results

```
ridZero(result: 3.0) // "3"
ridZero(result: 3.5) // "3.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 15, you can use this formatter:

`double.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(0...2)))`