# Format string with trailing zeros removed for x decimal places in Swift

Tags: swift, string-formatting

This in Swift (1.2)

```
let doubleValue1 = Double(10.116983123)
println(String(format: "%.2f", doubleValue1))

let doubleValue2 = Double(10.0)
println(String(format: "%.2f", doubleValue2))
```

Prints

```
10.12
10.00
```

I'm looking for a way **using a formatter or a direct string format** and not via string manipulation, to remove the trailing zeroes, so to print:

```
10.12
10
```

The closest I got is:

```
let doubleValue3 = Double(10.0)
println(String(format: "%.4g", doubleValue3))
```

But `g` uses significant digits, which means I would have to calculate my decimals digits separately. This sounds like an ugly solution.

Demo: http://swiftstub.com/651566091/

Any ideas? tia.

Comment: This question was expertly answered yesterday in this excellent post from Martin R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621338/formatting-decimal-places-with-unknown-number/30622335#30622335

Comment: yesterday? remarkable :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have to use NumberFormatter:

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    print(formatter.string(from: 1.0000)!) // 1
    print(formatter.string(from: 1.2345)!) // 1.23
```

This example will print 1 for the first case and 1.23 for the second; the number of minimum and maximum decimal places can be adjusted as you need.

Comment: Great, I just added `formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1` so if I the number on the left is zero it won't remove it, (0.200 will be 0.2 instead of .2)