# Swift - How to remove a decimal from a float if the decimal is equal to 0?

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point

I'm displaying a distance with one decimal, and I would like to remove this decimal in case it is equal to 0 (ex: 1200.0Km), how could I do that in swift?
I'm displaying this number like this:

```
let distanceFloat: Float = (currentUser.distance! as NSString).floatValue
distanceLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", distanceFloat) + "Km"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Remove Trailing Zeros From Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560743/swift-remove-trailing-zeros-from-double)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

**Swift 3/4:**

```
var distanceFloat1: Float = 5.0
var distanceFloat2: Float = 5.540
var distanceFloat3: Float = 5.03

extension Float {
    var clean: String {
       return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}

print("Value \(distanceFloat1.clean)") // 5
print("Value \(distanceFloat2.clean)") // 5.54
print("Value \(distanceFloat3.clean)") // 5.03
```

**Swift 2 (Original answer)**

```
let distanceFloat: Float = (currentUser.distance! as NSString).floatValue
distanceLabel.text = String(format: distanceFloat == floor(distanceFloat) ? “%.0f" : "%.1f", distanceFloat) + "Km"
```

Or as an extension:

```
extension Float {
    var clean: String {
        return self % 1 == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this line before `distanceFloat = floor(distanceFloat * 10) / 10` and then it worked perfectly, thanks :)

Comment: For Double,

extension Double {
    var clean: String {
        return self % 1 == 0 ? String(format: "%.0d", self) : String(self)
    }
}

Comment: This will not work if the float is something like 3.01.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: It doesn't work for this 123456738.0 number, the converted number comes as 123456736

Comment: `String(self)` need to replace to `"\(self)"`. But MirekE answer is better.

Comment: @Abo3atef what does the `%.0d` do, as opposed to `%.0f`? I am using the latter in my Double extension and seems to work fine

Answer (score 158):

Use NSNumberFormatter:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

// Avoid not getting a zero on numbers lower than 1
// Eg: .5, .67, etc...
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

let nums = [3.0, 5.1, 7.21, 9.311, 600.0, 0.5677, 0.6988]

for num in nums {
    print(formatter.string(from: num as NSNumber) ?? "n/a")
}
```

Returns:

3

5.1

7.21

9.31

600

0.57

0.7

Comment: for Swift 3: 
```let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
statLabel.text = formatter.string(from: value as NSNumber) ?? "n/a"```

Comment: How about 0.3000, I try this get .3;
I set its style ```formatter.numberStyle = .decimal```

Comment: @stanliu is correct, if you don't add the `.decimal` numberStyle numbers below 1 will display without a zero. Eg: .5, .78, etc...
Editing the answer now.

Comment: I have this number - 5.7156 but when I used code from this answer then I get output: 5.72.  anyone know why?

Comment: @GaneshPawar maximumFractionDigits is set to 2 . If you need 4 decimal places set it to 4

Answer (score 57):

`extension` is the powerful way to do it.

**Extension**:

Code for Swift 2 (not Swift 3 or newer):

```
extension Float {
    var cleanValue: String {
        return self % 1 == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var sampleValue: Float = 3.234
print(sampleValue.cleanValue)
```

> 3.234

```
sampleValue = 3.0
print(sampleValue.cleanValue)
```

> 3

```
sampleValue = 3
print(sampleValue.cleanValue)
```

> 3

Sample Playground file is [here](https://github.com/AshokKumarYes/CleanFloatSample).

Answer (score 41):

**Update of accepted answer for swift 3**:

```
extension Float {
    var cleanValue: String {
        return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}
```

usage would just be:

```
let someValue: Float = 3.0

print(someValue.cleanValue) //prints 3
```

Answer (score 24):

To format it to String, follow this pattern

```
let aFloat: Float = 1.123

let aString: String = String(format: "%.0f", aFloat) // "1"
let aString: String = String(format: "%.1f", aFloat) // "1.1"
let aString: String = String(format: "%.2f", aFloat) // "1.12"
let aString: String = String(format: "%.3f", aFloat) // "1.123"
```

To cast it to Int, follow this pattern

```
let aInt: Int = Int(aFloat) // "1"
```

When you use `String(format:` initializer, Swift will automatically round the final digit as needed based on the following number.

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 5.5** makes it easy

Just use the new `formatted()` api with a default `FloatingPointFormatStyle`:

```
let values: [Double] = [1.0, 4.5, 100.0, 7]
for value in values {
    print(value.formatted(FloatingPointFormatStyle()))
}
// prints "1, 4.5, 100, 7"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use an extension as already mentioned, this solution is a little shorter though:

```
extension Float {
    var shortValue: String {
        return String(format: "%g", self)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var sample: Float = 3.234
print(sample.shortValue)
```

Comment: Will fail for `0.00000001`. See documentation of %g at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html: "_The style used depends on the value converted; style e (or E ) shall be used only if the exponent resulting from such a conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision._"

Answer (score 10):

Swift 5 
for Double it's same as @Frankie's answer for float

```
var dec: Double = 1.0
dec.clean // 1
```

for the extension

```
extension Double {
    var clean: String {
       return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

In **Swift 4** try this.

```
    extension CGFloat{
        var cleanValue: String{
            //return String(format: 1 == floor(self) ? "%.0f" : "%.2f", self)
            return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(format: "%.2f", self)//
        }
    }
```

//How to use - if you enter more then two-character after (.)point, it's automatically cropping the last character and only display two characters after the point.

```
let strValue = "32.12"
print(\(CGFloat(strValue).cleanValue)
```

Comment: Will not trim the zero from value `1.1`: output will be `"1.10"`.

Comment: @Cœur it's used for display two value after point(.). if you want to display only one value then used "            return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(format: "%.1f", self)//
"

Comment: I know... I was just describing how your code differs from some other answers behavior.

Answer (score 5):

## Formatting with maximum fraction digits, without trailing zeros

This scenario is good when a custom output precision is desired.
This solution seems roughly as fast as NumberFormatter + NSNumber [solution from MirekE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31390870/1033581), but one benefit could be that we're avoiding NSObject here.

```
extension Double {
    func string(maximumFractionDigits: Int = 2) -> String {
        let s = String(format: "%.\(maximumFractionDigits)f", self)
        var offset = -maximumFractionDigits - 1
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: -maximumFractionDigits, by: -1) {
            if s[s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: i - 1)] != "0" {
                offset = i
                break
            }
        }
        return String(s[..<s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: offset)])
    }
}
```

(works also with `extension Float`, but not the macOS-only type `Float80`)

Usage: `myNumericValue.string(maximumFractionDigits: 2)` or `myNumericValue.string()`

Output for `maximumFractionDigits: 2`:

> 1.0 → "1"
> 0.12 → "0.12"
> 0.012 → "0.01"
> 0.0012 → "0"
> 0.00012 → "0"

Answer (score 4):

NSNumberFormatter is your friend

```
let distanceFloat: Float = (currentUser.distance! as NSString).floatValue
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.positiveFormat = "###0.##"
let distance = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(float: distanceFloat))!
distanceLabel.text = distance + " Km"
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple :

```
Int(floor(myFloatValue))
```

Comment: Doesn't this always remove the decimal? OP doesn't want that.

Comment: This will remove decimals always, not only when .0

Answer (score 3):

*Here's the full code.*

```
let numberA: Float = 123.456
let numberB: Float = 789.000

func displayNumber(number: Float) {
    if number - Float(Int(number)) == 0 {
        println("\(Int(number))")
    } else {
        println("\(number)")
    }
}

displayNumber(numberA) // console output: 123.456
displayNumber(numberB) // console output: 789
```

*Here's the most important line in-depth.*

```
func displayNumber(number: Float) {
```

1. Strips the float's decimal digits with `Int(number)`.
2. Returns the stripped number back to float to do an operation with `Float(Int(number))`.
3. Gets the decimal-digit value with `number - Float(Int(number))`
4. Checks the decimal-digit value is empty with `if number - Float(Int(number)) == 0`

*The contents within the if and else statements doesn't need explaining.*

Comment: In your case, you'd want to make the function return `String` and instead of the `println(result)` do `return result`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful too.

```
extension Float {
    func cleanValue() -> String {
        let intValue = Int(self)
        if self == 0 {return "0"}
        if self / Float (intValue) == 1 { return "\(intValue)" }
        return "\(self)"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let number:Float = 45.23230000
number.cleanValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` could help you :)

```
let aFloat: Float = 1.000

let aString: String = String(format: "%.1f", aFloat) // "1.0"

let wantedString: String = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".0", withString: "") // "1"
```

Comment: This would break a value like 1.05 --> 15

Comment: @Starceaker No, `1.05` execute `String(format: "%.1f", aFloat)` first will be `1.0`, works. if `1.05` execute `String(format: "%.2f", aFloat)` will be `1.05`, and than should do this `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".00"...)`