# Convert a x.0 float to int function

Tags: swift

Ok, kinda hard question to ask in a title, but here is what i want to do.

I want to basically detect if my float has a 0 after the . so that i can skip printing out the - for example - 1.0 and just print 1. Anyone have an idea as to how to do this ?
I was thinking of some sort of modulus operator but cant really figure out a good way for that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390466/swift-how-to-remove-a-decimal-from-a-float-if-the-decimal-is-equal-to-0

Comment: yes it did. sorry, couldn't formulate that question to find it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try 'flooring' the double value then checking if it is unchanged:

```
let dbl = 2.0
let isInteger = floor(dbl) == dbl // true
```

Fails if it is not an integer

```
let dbl = 2.4
let isInteger = floor(dbl) == dbl // false
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 and 4 :**

```
var FloatVal : Float = 4.0


extension Float {
    var truncate: String {
       return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}

print("Value \(FloatVal.truncate)") // 4
```