# Remove trailing numbers from String

Tags: swift, string, numbers, trailing

I am receiving two kid of Doubles from JSON:

`1.12` and `0.00007067999999`

The second number switches automatically to scientific notation(
7.067e-05), so I'm using the function `String(format:"%.8f", NUMBER)` to make it `0.00007067`, yes it works, but now my first number becomes `1.12000000`.
How to clean trailing numbers?

I've tried with [Swift - Remove Trailing Zeros From Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560743/swift-remove-trailing-zeros-from-double) , but the `%g` format changes second number to scientific notation again, so `%g` is not an option. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to store the actual numbers as doubles, you shouldn't care that the value is __displayed__ using the scientific notation. If you want to store the numbers as Strings, but make them have less fractional digits, you should use a `NumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NumberFormater` and set minimum and maximum fraction digits:

```
let double1 = 1.12
let double2 = 0.00007067999999

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
numberFormatter.string(for: double1) ?? ""   // "1.12"
numberFormatter.string(for: double2) ?? ""   // "0.00007068"
```

if you would like to round the fraction digits down you can set the formatter rounding mode option to `.down`:

```
numberFormatter.roundingMode = .down
numberFormatter.string(for: double2) ?? ""   // "0.00007067"
```