# Dynamic trim double

Tags: swift

What I want.

A: $1.10 = $1.1

B: $0.10101010101 = $0.101010

What I've tried

Solution one -
String(format: "%.6f", price)

This will do the following:

A: $1.100000
B: $0.1010101

So B is gets the correct outcome but A gets more decimals.

Solution two -
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
This gives the following outcome

A: $1.1
B: $0.1

So here A is correct but B gets rounded up.

Comment: Please, show us the exact code and your input data. Did you try to set number of decimal digits for `NumberFormatter`?

Comment: after Solution one.. https://newbedev.com/swift-remove-trailing-zeros-from-double

Comment: The question says "Double" but it seems like you're actually asking about a `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for removing trailing zeros

let distanceFloat1: Float = 1.10
let distanceFloat2: Float = 0.10101010101

```
print("Value \(distanceFloat1.clean)")

print("Value \(distanceFloat2.clean)") 

extension Float {
    var clean: String {
       return self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
    }
}
```

Output

```
Value 1.1
Value 1.101010
```

if you want to remove trailing zeros, also want to remove decimals after x place use

[Swift - Remove Trailing Zeros From Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560743/swift-remove-trailing-zeros-from-double)

Comment: I like this, its very clean

Comment: I do not understand the logic. This will print 1.1 as "1.1", and 1.0 as "1.000000". Also the output of the second number is "0.1010101", and not "0.101010" as you claim.

Comment: Your last edit didn't fix the problem for 0.10101010101 and now this is an exact duplicate of the answer posted by OP

Comment: Your latest version is an exact copy of (e.g.) the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946921/1187415.

Comment: This is just fundamentally flawed. I'm not sure why everyone has the constant drive towards `String(format:)`, when `NumberFormatter` already exists, and is *actually correct*.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the trailing zeros using Ben's answer.

```
var stringWithoutZeroFraction: String {
    return truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
}
```

Comment: You are aware that this answer isn't correct and will not produce the result you asked for?